Probability of drawing 2 specific cards out of 4, with 3 attempts
Related to a game I play with friends: Say there are 4 unique cards, for ease of explanation, let's say the Ace of each suit. I want to get the Ace of hearts and the Ace of diamonds, but don't care about the other two.
On the first random draw, I would have  50% chance of getting one of the two Aces I want. Let's say I draw the spade. The spade stays out, so on my next draw I have a 66.6% chance of getting one of the Aces I want.
Now, my question: what are the odds of getting BOTH Aces I want, over 3 random draws, where the drawn card stays out?
As far as I can tell (through brute force listing out every draw order possibility) I have a 50/50 shot of getting the two cards I want. But, I can't figure out a mathematical way to determine that.

Hint: each card is equally likely to be the last one drawn.

You can think of this as what is the probability that the card you do not draw is one of the cards you do not want. Because you want to draw two out of the four cards there is an equal chance that the card you don't draw is a red ace or black ace. Hence, your answer of 50% is correct.

I will introduce some notation to make this easier. We will denote the Ace of Spades, Hearts, Clubs, and Diamonds by $S,H,D,C$ respectively.
The set $\{ S, D\}$ implies that we have chosen 2 cards, the Ace of Spades and the Ace of Diamonds. Note that the order of choosing does not matter to us in this problem.
Thus our outcome space is all possible cardinality 3 subsets of $\{ S,D,H,C\}.$ These can be listed easily since a cardinality 3 subset is essentially the $\{ S,D,H,C\}$ without one element.
Put another way, the problem of choosing 3 cards out of 4 is the same as the problem of not choosing one card out of 4. This gives 4 possibilities for the cardinality 3 subsets.
Which are $\Omega = \{ \{ S,D,H \},\{ S,D,C \}, \{ D,H,C \}, \{ S,H,C \} \}.$
Out of these, the subsets of interest are $\{ S,D,H \}$ and $\{ D,H,C \}.$
Which gives us the probability $\frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$ which is 50% as you stated.

Aside from the brute-force finding the subsets, here is another way to think about this: We want to find the number of choices in which Diamonds and Hearts are part of the 3 cards we choose. Since we know Diamonds and Hearts are already part of the three cards, we only have the third card which is not fixed. There are 2 choices for the 3rd card, Spades and Clubs. This gives 2 choices. Of course, it is 4 total choices of 3 cards, by the same argument as earlier.
Hence it is 50%.

Might be overkill, but a tree diagram always feels like home to me! To calculate the probability of winning (getting your two desired cards), all that has to be done is to locate each path that leads to a win, and add together the probabilities of each of those victory-leading paths happening. In your case (from left to right):
Probability of path 1 occurring:
$\frac{2}{4}\times\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$
Probability of path 2 occurring:
$\frac{2}{4}\times\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{6}$
Probability of path 3 occurring:
$\frac{2}{4}\times\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{6}$
Alas, the probability of winning is:
$\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$, or 50%, as you said.
Brute force doesn't mean non-mathematical, just maybe less efficient at times :)


While it is good to know slick shortcuts, e.g. Lulu's suggestion that each card is equally likely to be the last one, I am giving a general way of tackling such problems which you should know.
Drawing cards without replacement in any order is what is called an unordered selection from a hypergeometric distribution. The terms may seem frightening, but the formula is simple and intuitive
Here it translates to finding the probability of getting both the wanted cards and one unwanted card
$Pr= \dfrac{\binom22\binom21}{\binom43} = \dfrac12$
